# Get counts of each associations record with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Say I have a Car model with many associated models, some has_many, others has_one.

```
class Car
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :steering, class_name: "Car::Steering", autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steering, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :tires, class_name: "Car::Tire", autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tires, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :doors, class_name: "Car::Door", autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :doors, allow_destroy: true
end
```

How do I list each `Car` record and show a count of each associated model record?

I want to return something like:

```
parts = { steering: 1, doors: 4 }
```

I know I can go one by one on each association and return the count, but what if I have 100 associations? I want to make it dynamic.

**EDIT:**

I can get an array of all associated has_many and has_one records with

```
car = Car.first
Car.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many, :has_one).map(&:name)
 => [:steering, :tires, :doors, ...]
```

Comment: Do you know you could also have `embedded` associations in your model too? Do you want to include them in your count?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I really don't mind how those records are associated, whether they are embedded or associated. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I had the exact same solution you posted below. :)

Comment: If you need all types of association counts, you might need to change it to `reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many, :has_one, :embeds_one, :embeds_many, :has_and_belongs_to_many, :belongs_to, etc.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
selected_car = Car.first
selected_car.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many, :has_one)
   .map do |assoc|
     { assoc.name => (car.send(assoc.name).nil? ? 0 : car.send(assoc.name).count) }
   end
```

If you have a better, faster, more efficient solution, please do share!

UPDATE:

Found a problem with my above code. :has_one associations cannot be counted and will return an error. So this will work instead:

```
one_assoc = selected_car.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).map { |assoc| selected_car.send(assoc.name).present? ? {assoc.name => 1 } : nil }
many_assoc = selected_car.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map { |assoc| selected_car.send(assoc.name).present? ? {assoc.name => selected_car.send(assoc.name).count } : nil }
associations = one_assoc + many_assoc
```